# D-type LATCH output when minimum clock/enable pulse width is violated and input/output are the same

Tags: latch, metastability

Can the output of a D-type latch go metastable when:

1. There is a minimum CLK/ENable pulse width violation
2. The input and the output of the latch have the same value?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. I'm pretty certain it's a 'no' but I'm afraid I don't have the time to write the decent and substantiated answer this needs.

Comment: By latch, do you really mean latch or actually mean a flip-flop? (A latch lets its input flow to its output while its CLK/EN is at one level and holds its value while CLK/EN is at the opposite level. A flip-flop transfers input to output on a CLK edge,)

Comment: Any logic block is ideal, and the behaviour how it works under various conditions depends on the implementation.

Comment: I think OP means a latch, because the basic D-type flip flop does not have an enable.

Comment: @SteveSh, I think so too, but FPGA registers as FFs (eg a DFFE) have CLK and EN. OP: please edit your question to clarify what technology you are considering here and why.

Comment: Here I was referring really to D-latch and not D-FF. I'm asking this question because in the lib file of the technology we are using, the latch model is generating X at the output when there is a short pulse on the enable even though Q and D are the same

Comment: The model will complain of timing violations and signal this with an X, regardless of what the real one will do. Which I imagine you realised. Incidentally, please edit new information into your question rather than adding it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question.